# existence of solutions of an over-determined system over finite fields

Tags: c++, c, matlab, math

Does anyone know how to determine whether or not a linear equation array over finite fields has at least a solution? Basically, I have xA=b, where x has length n and A has size n by m. When m>n, the system over-determined. I know if everything is over real number, the condition would be AA'b=b, where A' is the pseudo-inverse of A. But how about system over finite field? I am primarily using MATLAB, and pinv(A) doesnt work for A over finite fields.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't get any bites on this question, you might consider moving it to math.SE since it is, at its heart, a math question rather than a programming question. (Based on my limited experience with finite field algebra I won't be surprised if the answer turns out to be that you have to use a brute-force approach. Hopefully that's not the case though.)

Comment: You are talking about Galois fields in MATLAB?

Comment: @chappjc, yes, it is.

Comment: @nispio, thanks for the suggestion. I am new to the forum, where is math.SE?

Comment: [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the Communications System Toolbox, so I can't try anything here out, but to check if your system for existence and/or uniqueness of solutions, try [`gfrank`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfrank.html).  Check if the rank of the matrix is equal to the number of rows (unique solution). Rather, [compare `rank([A,b])` and `rank(A)`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/12/11/how-to-check-for-existence-of-solution-to-matrix-equations), although I don't know if Galois field objects concatenate like that.

Then use the backslash operator (`\` a.ka. `mldivide`) to solve the system `Ax=b`.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp6073) for examples of linear algebra with Galois fields.

Comment: Cool!  This works for me.  Note that if you are dealing in row vectors (as is common in FF) then you will need to use the transposes of everything (ie `A.'\b.'`) since `mldivide` is for column vectors.

Comment: That is exactly the correct solution. I just dig this out from my old textbooks... Thank you chappjc!